# What happens to charged particle during the process of conversion from matter to antimatter?

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws, charge, antimatter

During the conversion, there is a brief moment in which proton has no electric charge? (during the switch phase from plus to minus) Could it be that in this moment proton has no electromagnetic properties and thus 0 mass? (is electromagnetism responsible for atomic mass?)

Comment: You cannot convert matter to antimatter. Do you mean the combination of matter and antimatter to make electrically neutral radiation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is absolutely wrong, if you have a given particle (anti-particle), this particle (anti-particle) can't change its nature. A particle remains a particle and an anti-particle remains an anti-particle. Nothing else.

What can happens, is that particle and anti-particle can interact between each other, for example, a basic process is the following:
$$ e_{+}+ e_{-} \rightarrow 2\gamma$$
This means that an electron, during the scattering process (interaction process) with his anti-particle, that is the positron, produce as a result 2 photons.

In any case, also the interaction processes are characterized by some conservation laws,as the conservation of the electric charge, or the energy. In the case above, you can see immediately that the conservation of the electric charge is respected; in fact, if you sum the charge of a particle and the charge of its anti-particle, you will obtain 0, that is the charge of the photon $\gamma$ (i.e. the charge of an anti-particle has got the same modulus but opposite sign with respect to the particle which is referred).

Comment: Thank you, now I understand correctly how antimatter is made at CERN however we still can convert photons (by collisions) to positron and electron and then convert them back to photon or gamma, the question is: is there a measurable moment that exists between  a particle state and gamma radiation/photon state ?